# How to reset Modal body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to `append` body of the bootstrap modal dynamically. Here is the body Markup of the Modal.

```
 <!-- try to indent the codes for readability -->
 <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="row text-left" style="margin-left: 2em;">
         <div class="form-group"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

and here is the Jquery code to append the contents on click event of a button.

```
$('.form-group').append(EditHTML);
```

`EditHTML` is the markup that got generated dynamically. Now issue is that with every button click event `EditHTML` is being added with the previous content. I need to reset the Modal, each time button is click.Please help.

Comment: give some `id` to div whic contains your body and reset the body using id and then append your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$('.form-group').html(EditHTML);
```

> **Description :** When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any
>   content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new
>   content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements
>   with the new content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood right：

```
$('.form-group').html(EditHTML);
```